# Downloading blob text returning strange text

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am downloading the text of a blob I upload, but the text returned contains a lot of jargon, such as the following:

```
��\u0011\u0871\u001a�\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0>\0\u0003\0��\t\0\u0006\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\u0003\0\0\02\u0001\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\u0010\0\05\u0001\0\0\u0001\0\0\0����\0\0\0\0/\u0001\0\00\u0001\0\01\u0001\0\0�����������������������������������������������
```

I am using the following to download the text:

```
string FileText = "";
FileText = blockBlob.DownloadText();
```

I have tried the following as well(That was suggested) but does not fix the issue :

```
 FileText = blockBlob.DownloadText(Encoding.UTF8);
```

I have also tried the following:

```
 FileText = blockBlob.DownloadText(Encoding.Unicode);
```

Is there a way to avoid this jargon to be included ?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What format was the blob encoded in? Also, this is always good reading on the topic: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/ This helps you understand "the jargon", and why it's included.

Comment: Thanks. Was an interesting read.

Comment: Sorry, to answer your question, I believe the DownloadText by default uses UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

`"\u0011\u0871\u001a"` (via UTF8) consists of the bytes `0x11 0xE0 0xA1 0xB1 0x1A` which form part of the header for a Compound File, in this case it appears to be for a Microsoft Word .Doc File.

Download it to a byte array any you will have something you can write to disk.

Comment: Thanks. Could you possibly provide an example. Im new to all of this

Comment: What's "FileText"? What's its type? If you convert it to a byte array, you can easily write it out to a file with .doc extension and see if it does indeed open as a Word Document. You can simply use 

File.WriteAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)

for that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am uploading the .doc file to a blob storage and trying to retrieve the text from that blob so that I can extract certain things from it, so writing it to a .doc again unfortunately wont solve my issue. I have written it to a byte array(byte[]) and then tried using the GetString() from encoding to convert it back to UTF8, but I get the same result. Any other suggestions?

Comment: That's not going to work I'm afraid; A Word file is not text its a binary file, you cannot treat it like a text file and simply read from it.  You either need to upload plain-text or download the .doc and use Word interop or similar from C# to programmatically access the document and then the text contained within it.